# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic - error after NET6 migration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, kestrel

I have already updated my app (asp.net API) from NetCore3.1 to Net6. There was no breaking changes. To build my app I use command

> dotnet publish --runtime win-x64 --self-contained -c release -o build

When I run app on local env everything works fine, but when I copy package into CICD server I get error when app is starting

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic, Version=6.0.0.0, PublicKey=adb9...'. The system cannot find the file specified.

There is such dll in bin folder, but different version (ver 6.0.4 and public key started with f9ae).
I don't understand why correct version isn't present in build folder (I publish as self-contained).
How can I check where is such DLL located on my local environment (can I log it)? What should I do to finish migration to NET6?

Comment: I try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic 6.0.0-preview.6.21355.2`, and then publish my application, I can retrieve the corresponding dll under the publish folder, and it does not appear that you encountered of this question. Can you share your steps and what have you tried?

Comment: Check for appropriate dll in bin and its extension in web.config are there. When you publish the ASP.NET CORE application to server, please make sure its dependences are all available on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer, on server there was old **app.runtime.json** which made mess with dependencies.

Please remember to update **[app].runtime.json** when you migrate from NetCore3.1 to NET6 :)